# WSGIServer with '0.0.0.0' error - an integer is required (got type bytes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgiserver

I'm running `WSGIServer` with an address `'0.0.0.0'`

```
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5002), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)

    server.serve_forever()
```

Which generates the error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)`

If I change `'0.0.0.0'` to `'127.0.0.1'` everything works just fine.

I'm using Python 3.8 on MacOS 10.14.6

Here is the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/streaming_server.py", line 174, in run_process
        server.serve_forever()   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 367, in serve_forever
        self.start()   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 305, in start
        self.init_socket()   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1491, in init_socket
        self.update_environ()   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 1503, in update_environ
        name = socket.getfqdn(address[0])   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 269, in getfqdn
        hostname, aliases, _ = gethostbyaddr(name)   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 241, in gethostbyaddr
        return get_hub().resolver.gethostbyaddr(ip_address)   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/resolver/thread.py", line 68, in gethostbyaddr
        return self.pool.apply(_socket.gethostbyaddr, args, kwargs)   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/pool.py", line 159, in apply
        return self.spawn(func, *args, **kwds).get()   
File "src/gevent/event.py", line 268, in gevent._event.AsyncResult.get   
File "src/gevent/event.py", line 296, in gevent._event.AsyncResult.get 
File "src/gevent/event.py", line 286, in gevent._event.AsyncResult.get 
File "src/gevent/event.py", line 266, in gevent._event.AsyncResult._raise_exception   
File "src/gevent/event.py", line 211, in gevent._event.AsyncResult.exc_info.__get__   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_tblib.py", line 371, in g
        return f(a)   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_tblib.py", line 432, in load_traceback
        return loads(s)   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_tblib.py", line 337, in unpickle_traceback
        return ret.as_traceback()   
File "/Users/ronharlev/Documents/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_tblib.py", line 202, in as_traceback
        code = CodeType( TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @Selcuk MacOS 10.14.6 Updated the post too.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas added full error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1491:

> gevent 1.4 is not compatible with Python 3.8. Please use gevent >=
>   1.5a2 on Python 3.8. This is one of the (several) known issues of running gevent 1.4 on Python 3.8.